# Shouldn't questions not related to franchise belong to meta?

Tags: discussion

I have just found [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/120560/7885). While it is really nice idea, in my opinion it has nothing to do with actual Star Wars franchise. It is a fake image inside a funny game-like question.

Shouldn't questions like this be asked here, on meta?

Comment: And disregarding if it fits on the main site or not, the reason a question like this would fit on meta at all, would be...?

Comment: @TARS Still, the same argument could be made for asking whether Narnia could be considered sci-fi, which is apparently a meta question :-/

Comment: @randal'thor Well, yeah, and indeed I actually do consider those "what's the genre" questions a better fit on the main site, too. ;-)

Comment: We have a history of these questions, which are well received and rely on our expert knowledge to identify when the artist doesn't list it or is unavailable. Right now we do one or two a month, so they're not really in danger of overwhelming the site. They're typically small enough scale to be reasonable, as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Science Fiction and Fantasy Meta is for questions about the Science Fiction and Fantasy StackExchange website. The question you've linked is not asking about that site, so it does not belong on this Meta site.

Answer (score 9):

### No.

The meta site is for discussions **about the main site**, e.g. policy discussions, bug reports, or feature requests.

The question you link to is nothing to do with Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange, so it doesn't belong on the meta site. It is about science fiction / fantasy, so it belongs on the main site (provided it's considered on-topic - e.g. not a list question etc. - which in this case it is).

Comment: You were ninja'd.